# Xcode Simulator - CyMemDef.dylib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working on a new Macbook and just downloaded and installed Xcode with developer tools.

I have create a brand new project in Xcode (no modification or adding framework / pods). I am trying to run the same on simulator. When I do, my app crashes with "SIGABRT". The log shows the following message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /Library/Application Support/Cylance/Desktop/CyMemDef.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/80FC5E5D-2979-48C9-94F6-6C6D2A8073E6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B438FB0C-79A7-445E-B381-5D7E9247623B/demo.app/demo
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Library/Application Support/Cylance/Desktop/CyMemDef.dylib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
```

Comment: Same problem on my site. This seems to be a library of the Cylance Protect Software. Old projects start without problems. Only new projects have that problem in XCODE 10.1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution for me was to change my project's iOS Deployment Target to 11.4 or earlier.

With iOS Deployment Target 12.0, the app crashes every time!

I am running Xcode 10.0 and Cylance 2.0.1500.518 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.

Comment: Thank you -- that worked. I wonder what the problem is with the iOS 12.0 simulator and Cylance

Comment: Upgraded to macOS Mojave 10.14.3 and Cylance 2.0.1510.510 and the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 5):

Had similar trouble with CryptoKit, which was available only in iOS 13 and higher (while project was targeted iOS 9.3). It appeared that CryptoKit was not marked as `weak` for some reason. Adding `-weak_framework CryptoKit` into target's Build Settings > Other Linker Flags solved the problem for me:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another cause for the same error.

Having a misconfigured custom `modulemap` file can also be the cause of this issue.

In my case, this was the error:

```
--- framework module XXYZ {
+++ module XXYZ {
    header "SomethingCustom-header.h"
}
```